# Check if a string is equal to an object attribute from an entity

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, entity, contains

I build up a little XCode project with SwiftUI and Core Data.
I have one entity with two attributes "uri" and "name". I also have a FetchRequest which gives me the objects from the entity(variable for that is "items").
My goal is to check if there is an object from items which contains a string that match to the "uri".
Important: I can't use loops!

Should look somehting like this:

```
if(items.uri.contains("Test")){
    print("working")
}else{
    print("error")
```

Comment: Are you good with using a a predicate, a core data query, to find what you are looking for within Core Data? If so I can type something up for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
if items.contains(where: { $0.uri == "Test" }) {
    print("working")
} else {
    print("error")
}
```